# Unable to open CSV file from internet using C#

Tags: c#

I'm new with C#. I've written code to open a CSV file from my documents on my local machine. It works well and the data parsing works. Trouble is when I change the code to open the file from an internet site I cannot get it to work. I am able to open this file using VBA but I now want to use C# ADO.NET. I cannot find the answer by searching with Google. Can anyone help with the code and/or point me to a website with a good tutorial. All help much appreciated. Code attached, I'm sure the problem is with lines 24 - 26;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //
            // Read in a file line-by-line, and store it all in a List.
            //
            int i = 0;
            DateTime dte;
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            float[] Prices = new float[4];

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();

            byte[] data = wc.DownloadData("http://www.datasource.com/apps/qt/csv/pricehistory.ac?section=yearly_price_download&code=XXX");

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(wc))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //list.Add(line); // Add to list.
                    Console.WriteLine(line); // Write to console.

                    string[] parts = line.Split(',');
                    int DateSetter = 1;
                    int DateDone = 0;
                    int CountFloat = 0;
                    int PricesDone = 0;
                    Double Volume = 0;

                    foreach (string part in parts)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", i, part);

                        if (DateSetter == 1)
                        {
                            dte = DateTime.Parse(part);
                            DateSetter = 2;
                            Console.WriteLine(dte);
                        }
                        if (DateDone == 1)
                        {
                            if (DateSetter < 6)
                            {
                                Prices[CountFloat] = float.Parse(part);
                                CountFloat++;
                                DateSetter++;
                                Console.WriteLine(Prices[3]);
                            } 
                        }
                        DateDone = 1;
                        if (PricesDone == 1)
                        {
                            Volume = double.Parse(part);
                            Console.WriteLine(Volume);
                        }
                        if (DateSetter == 6)
                        {
                            PricesDone = 1;
                        }
                    }

                }
           }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you didn't include the exception details, or error message at all. If you're behind a proxy, that might be the reason and you'd have to use credentials in order for the program to access an external file.

Comment: Just "can't get it to work" is not useful as a description of the problem. What happens when you run the code, and how does that differ from what you expect? Do you get an excpetion, and in that case, which?

Comment: You're sure that is the exact sourcecode? `StreamReader`'s `ctor` doesn't have an overload for `WebClient`.

Comment: The message I'm getting when run debug is "URI formats are not supported" cheers

Comment: Please don't post code that doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as pasted would not compile. You can however use the `WebClient` to download to a string, then split the string into lines:

```
string content;
using(WebClient wc = new WebClient())
content = wc.DownloadString("http://www.datasource.com/apps/qt/csv/pricehistory.ac?section=yearly_price_download&code=XXX");

foreach(var line in content.Split(new string [] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None))
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to download data as you're doing, and then wrap it with a `MemoryStream`:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
byte[] data = wc.DownloadData(
    "http://www.datasource.com/apps/qt/csv/pricehistory.ac?section=yearly_price_download&code=XXX");

using (var ms = new MemoryStream(data))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(ms))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // do whatever
        }
    }
}
```

The advantage of this over splitting the string is that it uses considerably less memory.